# How do you combine Java and jxbrowser processes into a single custom named process?

Tags: java, process, jxbrowser

We have a pretty huge application that runs on JVM and relies heavily on jxbrowser.  Whenever we run our application we see the following process tree in task explorer (which does change from time to time unintentionally and by itself):

- Java(TM) Platform SE binary (32 bit) (5)

  - BrowserCore Chromium native Process
  - BrowserCore Chromium native Process
  - BrowserCore Chromium native Process
  - BrowserCore Chromium native Process
  - Java(TM) Platform SE binary

My goal is simple, make sure the process tree is always a single line with a set name [app name].

The reason is primarily security related; on high security networks, unidentified processes are a problem.

Failed solutions considered:

- Dname: windows and security software doesn't see it.
- Launch4j: process name tag is depreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible as JxBrowser has a multi-process architecture, which does not allow to combine everything in one .exe file.

Comment: Wow, that's terrible. Is there an alternative you might suggest to achieving my stated goal? If not, the second best thing would be to force the top most item of the process tree to be a defined as a custom name rather than generic Java name.